# Passing by reference to std::thread c++0x in VS2012

Tags: c++11, stdthread

```
void ThreadFn(int& i)
{
    cout<<"Hi from thread "<<i<<endl;
}
int x = 0;
void CreateThreads(vector<thread>& workers)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        workers.push_back(thread(&ThreadFn, x));
    }
}
```

I was expecting a compilation error in the thread creation (`workers.push_back(thread(&ThreadFn, x));`) since `x` should be passed by ref. 
I though the right syntax should've been:

```
workers.push_back(thread(&ThreadFn, std::ref(x)));
```

Of course, the code compiles fine and also behaves properly. I am using `VC11`. Any idea why this isn't being flagged?

Answer (score 3):

This is a VC11 bug, the `thread` object makes internal copies of the arguments (as it should) but then it doesn't forward them to the `ThreadFn` function correctly, so what happens is the reference binds to the `thread` object's internal `int` member.

GCC's `std::thread` used to have a similar bug because we used `std::bind` to implement it, but I replaced the use of `std::bind` with a different implementation detail that forwards the captured arguments to the function by value.